# Phase 10 wild card hits

Tags: phase-10

1 player has a run of 4567 its hit with a wildcard. I the hit the same run with an 8. Its not allowed the wild was declared as an 8.
Is this how that rule works?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the wild card was played as a 3 or an 8.  From your question, it sounds like it was played as an 8.  According to [the rules](https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/HHR41-Eng.pdf):

> Once a Wild card has been played in a Phase, it cannot be removed from that Phase for the rest of the round.

In other words, when the wild card is played, it is treated as being the card it was played as.  If it was played as an 8, then no player may hit the run with another 8.  If it was played as a 3, then you may hit with the 8.